# Browser address bar inline search options

Tags: browser, search

I often search from the browser address bar for a particular site. Specifically, I'm looking for the site, not *in* the site. What options exist to avoid going to the search engine page and instead go straight to the site that I've selected?

Comment: Why not use a bookmark? What's the difference between in/for?

Comment: @harrymc this is for going to sites that I don't use often, or have never used. For example, I hear about product Super Awesome Widgets, I go to the browser and start searching for it, not knowing that Widgets really ends in a Z. So the suggestion shows up in the address bar as SuperAwesomeWidgetz.com and I select it. It goes to my default search engine instead of to the selected site. Why does this matter? Partly optimization, partly to avoid some of the unnecessary BS that the internet spews at us every minute of the day.

Comment: The address bar is not as good as Google for searches and it doesn't correct spelling mistakes.